# Hide or encrypt credentials for JMeter completely?

Tags: java, jmeter

can I have some ideas on security in JMeter please?
in order to use JMeter behind a corporate proxy the following format can be used to launch from the command line:
jmeter -H localhost -P 8888 -u username -a password -N localhost

Once JMeter is opened (and usual https certificate process followed) I use JMeter recorder to access a corporate application and complete usual business processes (including entering login details).

There are at least two issues with this approach:

a) network scans record any java application being run, with credentials in plain text

b) the JMX file produced has credentials saved in plain text, from when user logs into any secure application.

For the first issue, is it possible to change the http.proxyPass and http.proxyUser values? If so, how best to secure them to prevent anyone monitoring the network from seeing them?

For second issue, how best to hide this information? Parameterize the relevant http requests after manually checking the entire project? The most secure way would be to avoid using the recorder but this would be impractical.
Thanks, D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any data will be stored in the [.jmx test script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) as plain text.

If you don't want it to appear there you can:

1. Add [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) and define the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) reference names with their respective values which you want to substitute there
2. During recording [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) will automatically substitute the values with the JMeter Variables
3. Replace hard-coded sensitive values with [__P() functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)
4. When you will be executing JMeter test you will be able to [provide values in the runtime via `-J` command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) as:

   ```
    jmeter -Jusername=secret-username -Jpassword=secret-password etc.
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the time Dmitri, I have some queries though, apologies if I am getting confused on points. Answer 4. When a Java application is launched from command line in my company (ie JMeter), all of the parameters are scanned by the company and recorded centrally (assuming the worst, it would also be possible for others to see these account details) - it has therefore been flagged as a security risk to launch an app using a username/password as parameters in the command line. Is there any way to eliminate passwords/accounts being clearly visible when launching the app?

Comment: For points 1 -3 we could perform parameterization on the JMX, including any recorded http requests - possible workflow would be to get rid of credentials before JMX is saved. Answer 2 - unsure how to supply variable values BEFORE the script is recorded? For one thing, we don't know the names of the parameters in the http request until we have them recorded (bearing in mind we may have a hundred or more http requests recorded for one short test scenario. Answer 3. I'm assuming UDV and __P() functions are essentially interchangeable in a high level view and are used for storing variables